# Handle ECONNRESET on socket.io server

Tags: socket.io

I have a socket.io (Still in version 0.9) server that needs to do some clean up every time a client disconnects. Occasionally if ther client disconnects improperly I get a

`socket error Error: read ECONNRESET`

which I understand means that the other end of a tcp connection disconnected abruptly. I want a way to catch this so I can run the clean up. Is there a way to catch this in the socket server

I have a function like

```
socket.on('error', function(err){
    //Catch the error 
});
```

but it doesn't get called.

Answer (score -4):

For me works perfectly following code:

```
sock.on('error', function(data) {
    console.log('ERROR:  Data:'+data);
});
```